# Ajax request to php working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new with AJAX and was just testing a simple chat application between two user roles in a core php based application. My application works fine on WAMP but the same application is not working on my live server. On live server I am not receiving any errors in console. I know the following might not be the best practice but this is just to test the ajax functionality and i can not figure out where the problem is. Thanks in advance for reading the long code.

Update : i forgot to add that sending messages is working and i can see the same in my db but the refresh function is not working

Below is my js

```
   $('#msgsend').click(function() { 

    var x;
    var x=document.getElementById("texty").value;       
    var sendDATA = new Array();
    sendDATA[0] = 'sendMessage';
    sendDATA[1] = '<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>';
    sendDATA[2] = x;
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['tid'])) { ?>
    sendDATA[3]='tid';
    <?php } else { ?>
    sendDATA[3]='uid';
    <?php } ?>
    sendDATA[4] = '<?php echo isset($_SESSION['tid'])?$_SESSION['tid']:$_SESSION['id'];?>';
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",   
          url: "helpers/chathelper.tpl.php",
          data: {'sendDATA': sendDATA},
          success: function(res){

                    document.getElementById("texty").value = "";

                  },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }       
     });
    });
    window.setInterval(function(){
         /// call your function here
    var chatDATA = new Array();
    chatDATA[0] = 'refreshChat';
    chatDATA[1] = '<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>';
    chatDATA[2] = '<?php echo isset($_SESSION['tid'])?$_SESSION['tid']:$_SESSION['id'];?>';
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['tid'])) { ?>
    chatDATA[3]='tid';
    <?php } else { ?>
    chatDATA[3]='uid';
    <?php } ?>
     $.ajax({ url: 'helpers/chathelper.tpl.php',
         data: {'chatDATA' : chatDATA },
         type: 'post',
         dataType:'html',
         success: function(data){
                if(data !== '')
                {console.log(data);
                $('#chat-main').append(data);
                $('#chat-main').animate({scrollTop: $('#chat-main').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);

                }

              },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log("Status: " + textStatus); console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }       
    });
      }, 2000);
    });
```

and below is my php

```
$chatDATA=$_POST['chatDATA'];
$sendDATA=$_POST['sendDATA'];
$uid;$tid;$mes;$token;$action;$type;
if(isset($chatDATA))
{
$action=$chatDATA[0];
$token=$chatDATA[1];
if(!strcmp($chatDATA[3],'uid'))
$uid=$chatDATA[2];
else if(!strcmp($chatDATA[3],'tid'))
$tid=$chatDATA[2];
$type=$chatDATA[3];
}
else if(isset($sendDATA))
{
$action=$sendDATA[0];
$token=$sendDATA[1];
$mes=$sendDATA[2];
$type=$sendDATA[3];
if(!strcmp($chatDATA[3],'uid'))
$uid=$chatDATA[4];
else if(!strcmp($chatDATA[3],'tid'))
$tid=$chatDATA[4];
}

switch($action){
    case "sendMessage" :
        sendmessage($uid,$tid,$mes,$token,$con);
    break;
    case "refreshChat" :
        refresh($uid,$tid,$token,$type,$con);
    break;
}


function sendmessage($uid,$tid,$mes,$token,$con){
$mes=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$mes);
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `token` = '".$token."'");
$key=mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_BOTH);
if($tid!=null && ($key[2]==$tid))
    {
      $trav= getTraveler($tid,$con);
      $mes=$trav[3].' : '.$mes;
      $res2 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `chat` (`uid`, `tid`, `jid`, `message`, `sender`, `unread`, `token`) VALUES('".$key[1]."','".$key[2]."','".$key[3]."','".$mes."','tid','0','".$token."')");
    }
else if($uid!=null && ($key[1]==$uid))
{
    $user=getUser($uid,$con);
    $mes=$user[3].' : '.$mes;
    $res2 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `chat` (`uid`, `tid`, `jid`, `message`, `sender`, `unread`, `token`) VALUES('".$key[1]."','".$key[2]."','".$key[3]."','".$mes."','uid','0','".$token."')");
}

else
return false;

}


function refresh($uid,$tid,$token,$type,$con)
{

if(isset($uid))
    $chat_read = mysqli_query($con,"select * from `chat_read` where `token`='" . $token . "' AND `uid`='".$uid."'");
else if (isset($tid)) 
    $chat_read = mysqli_query($con,"select * from `chat_read` where `token`='" . $token . "' AND `tid`='".$tid."'");
$get_read = mysqli_fetch_row($chat_read);
if (isset($get_read) && isset($type) && isset($uid)) {
    $read_sql = "SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `token`='" . $token . "' AND `id`>'" . $get_read[2] . "' ";
    $unread = mysqli_query($con,$read_sql);
    $html_output = "";
    $all_results = array();
    $last_id_updated;
    while ($message = mysqli_fetch_array($unread,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $all_results[] = $message;
    }
    $size_arr=mysqli_num_rows($unread);
    for ($i=0; $i < $size_arr; $i++) {

        if ($all_results[$i]['sender'] == "uid")
            $html_output .= '<li class="left clearfix"> <div class="chat-body1 clearfix"><p>'.$all_results[$i][message].'</p> <div class="chat_time pull-right">'.$all_results[$i][time].'</div> </div> </li>';
        else if ($all_results[$i]['sender'] == "tid")
            $html_output .= '<li class="left clearfix admin_chat"> <div class="chat-body1 clearfix"> <p>'.$all_results[$i][message].'</p> <div class="chat_time pull-left">'.$all_results[$i][time].'</div> </div> </li>';
    $last_id_updated=$all_results[$i]['id'];
    }
    if($size_arr) {
        if(isset($uid))
            $read_update="UPDATE `chat_read` SET `last_id_uid`= '".$last_id_updated."',`uid`='".$uid."' WHERE token='".$token."'";
        elseif (isset($tid))
            $read_update="UPDATE `chat_read` SET `last_id_tid`= '".$last_id_updated."',`tid`='".$tid."' WHERE token='".$token."'";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$read_update);}
    echo $html_output;

}
if (isset($get_read) && isset($type) && isset($tid)) {
    $read_sql = "SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `token`='" . $token . "' AND `id`>'" . $get_read[3] . "' ";
    $unread = mysqli_query($con,$read_sql);
    $html_output = "";
    $all_results = array();
    $last_id_updated;
    while ($message = mysqli_fetch_array($unread,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $all_results[] = $message;
    }
    $size_arr=mysqli_num_rows($unread);
    for ($i=0; $i < $size_arr; $i++) {

        if ($all_results[$i]['sender'] == "uid")
            $html_output .= '<li class="left clearfix"> <div class="chat-body1 clearfix"><p>'.$all_results[$i][message].'</p> <div class="chat_time pull-right">'.$all_results[$i][time].'</div> </div> </li>';
        else if ($all_results[$i]['sender'] == "tid")
            $html_output .= '<li class="left clearfix admin_chat"> <div class="chat-body1 clearfix"> <p>'.$all_results[$i][message].'</p> <div class="chat_time pull-left">'.$all_results[$i][time].'</div> </div> </li>';
        $last_id_updated=$all_results[$i]['id'];
    }
    if($size_arr) {
        if(isset($uid))
            $read_update="UPDATE `chat_read` SET `last_id_uid`= '".$last_id_updated."',`uid`='".$uid."' WHERE token='".$token."'";
        elseif (isset($tid))
            $read_update="UPDATE `chat_read` SET `last_id_tid`= '".$last_id_updated."',`tid`='".$tid."' WHERE token='".$token."'";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$read_update);}
    echo $html_output;


}

}
```

Comment: View the `Network` tab on your browser inspector. Are you getting a `200`? Are you getting a `500`? `404`? If you are getting a `200`, look at your payload and make sure everything is submitting.

Comment: Is there any reason for the url to be "helpers/chathelper.tpl.php" rather than "/helpers/chathelper.tpl.php" or "./helpers/chathelper.tpl.php"? Just wondering.

Comment: Where is `$con` defined? Are you connecting to your database correctly? Depending on how strict you have your error reporting, it may just be resolving to an internal server error.

Comment: @Daerik all 200 and i am not sure how to look at the payload.

Comment: @developerwjk No there is no reason but the send message functionality is working with it so i guess it has to be right

Comment: @Daerik $con is defined in a file named as db_connect.php and i am including it at the top of my php script using `require_once('../includes/db_connect.php');`

Comment: @HimanshuOberoi What does your response look like?

Comment: @Daerik I am not getting any response at all !! but on the localhost i am able to see the messages in the chat window as soon as i send them. I even tried to log the response to the console but i get nothing

Comment: @HimanshuOberoi I would suggest creating a simple form that you can manually type in your `POST` values. This will give you a good example if the script is even returning the correct data.

Comment: @Daerik About error reporting i have set it to E_ALL and i am only able to see some Notices for the Undefined variable sendDATA that is probably because i am using a single file to call two different functions and at a time   variables related to only one function are sent to the file and others remain undefined but are also not used in the function i am calling to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making some mistakes in DB query getting null response so i wrote the whole script again and took care of all the e and was getting null response Below is the Working Script.

**My JS**

```
 $('#msgsend').click(function() { 

        var x;
        var x=document.getElementById("texty").value;       
        var sendDATA = new Array();
        sendDATA[0] = 'sendMessage';
        sendDATA[1] = '<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>';
        sendDATA[2] = x;
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['tid'])) { ?>
        sendDATA[3]='tid';
        <?php } else { ?>
        sendDATA[3]='uid';
        <?php } ?>
        sendDATA[4] = '<?php echo isset($_SESSION['tid'])?$_SESSION['tid']:$_SESSION['id'];?>';
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",   
              url: "helpers/chathelper.tpl.php",
              data: {'sendDATA': sendDATA},
              success: function(res){

                        document.getElementById("texty").value = "";

                      },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                }       
         });
        });
        window.setInterval(function(){
             /// call your function here
        var chatDATA = new Array();
        chatDATA[0] = 'refreshChat';
        chatDATA[1] = '<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>';
        chatDATA[2] = '<?php echo isset($_SESSION['tid'])?$_SESSION['tid']:$_SESSION['id'];?>';
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['tid'])) { ?>
        chatDATA[3]='tid';
        <?php } else { ?>
        chatDATA[3]='uid';
        <?php } ?>
         $.ajax({ url: 'helpers/chathelper.tpl.php',
             data: {'chatDATA' : chatDATA },
             type: 'post',
             dataType:'html',
             success: function(data){
                    if(data !== '')
                    {console.log(data);
                    $('#chat-main').append(data);
                    $('#chat-main').animate({scrollTop: $('#chat-main').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);

                    }

                  },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    console.log("Status: " + textStatus); console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                }       
        });
          }, 2000);
        });
```

**and Below is the PHP**

```
session_start();
require_once('../includes/config.php');
require_once('../includes/db_connect.php');
require_once('../sources/functions.php');
require_once('dbhelper.php');

$chatDATA=$_POST['chatDATA'];
$sendDATA=$_POST['sendDATA'];
$uid;$tid;$id;$mes;$token;$action;$type;
if(isset($chatDATA))
{
    $action=$chatDATA[0];
    $token=$chatDATA[1];
    $id=$chatDATA[2];
    $type=$chatDATA[3];

}
else if(isset($sendDATA))
{
    $action=$sendDATA[0];
    $token=$sendDATA[1];
    $mes=$sendDATA[2];
    $type=$sendDATA[3];
    if(!strcmp($sendDATA[3],'uid'))
        $uid=$sendDATA[4];
    else if(!strcmp($sendDATA[3],'tid'))
        $tid=$sendDATA[4];
}

switch($action){
    case "sendMessage" :
        sendmessage($uid,$tid,$mes,$token,$con);
        break;
    case "refreshChat" :
        refresh($id,$token,$type,$con);
        break;
}


function sendmessage($uid,$tid,$mes,$token,$con){
    $mes=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$mes);
    $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `token` = '".$token."'");
    $key=mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_BOTH);
    if($tid!=null && ($key[2]==$tid))
    {
        $trav= getTraveler($tid,$con);
        $mes=$trav[3].' : '.$mes;
        $res2 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `chat` (`uid`, `tid`, `jid`, `message`, `sender`, `unread`, `token`) VALUES('".$key[1]."','".$key[2]."','".$key[3]."','".$mes."','tid','0','".$token."')");
        echo $mes;
    }
    else if($uid!=null && ($key[1]==$uid))
    {
        $user=getUser($uid,$con);
        $mes=$user[3].' : '.$mes;
        $res2 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `chat` (`uid`, `tid`, `jid`, `message`, `sender`, `unread`, `token`) VALUES('".$key[1]."','".$key[2]."','".$key[3]."','".$mes."','uid','0','".$token."')");
        echo $mes;
    }

    else
        return false;

}


function refresh($id,$token,$type,$con)
{
    if(isset($id)&&isset($token)&&isset($type)&&isset($con))
    {   
        $chat_sql="select * from `chat_read` where `token`='" . $token . "'";
        $chat_read = mysqli_query($con,$chat_sql);
        $get_read = mysqli_fetch_row($chat_read);
        if (isset($get_read) && isset($type) && isset($id)) {

                    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
                        $read_sql = "SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `token`='" . $token . "' AND `id`>'" . $get_read[5] . "' ";
                    else if(isset($_SESSION['tid']))
                        $read_sql = "SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `token`='" . $token . "' AND `id`>'" . $get_read[6] . "' ";

                    $unread = mysqli_query($con,$read_sql);
                    $html_output = "";
                    $all_results = array();
                    $last_id_updated=0;
                    while ($message = mysqli_fetch_array($unread,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                        $all_results[] = $message;
                    }

                    $size_arr=mysqli_num_rows($unread);
                    for ($i=0; $i < $size_arr; $i++)
                    {

                        if ($all_results[$i]['sender'] == "uid")
                        { $html_output .= '<li class="left clearfix"> <div class="chat-body1 clearfix"><p>'.$all_results[$i][message].'</p> <div class="chat_time pull-right">'.$all_results[$i][time].'</div> </div> </li>';}
                        else if ($all_results[$i]['sender'] == "tid")
                        {   $html_output .= '<li class="left clearfix admin_chat"> <div class="chat-body1 clearfix"> <p>'.$all_results[$i][message].'</p> <div class="chat_time pull-left">'.$all_results[$i][time].'</div> </div> </li>';}
                            $last_id_updated=$all_results[$i]['id'];
                        }
                        $read_update;
                    if($size_arr) {
                        if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
                        {   
                            $read_update="UPDATE `chat_read` SET `last_id_uid`= '".$last_id_updated."' WHERE token='".$token."'";
                        }
                        else  if(isset($_SESSION['tid']))
                        {
                            $read_update="UPDATE `chat_read` SET `last_id_tid`= '".$last_id_updated."' WHERE token='".$token."'";
                        }
                        $res=mysqli_query($con,$read_update);}
                        if($res)
                        echo $html_output;


                }

    }
}
```